# How to send array without "[]" using jQuery $.ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, servlets

If a html form has multiple inputs with the same name, a Servlet will understand it as Array:

**Form:**

```
<form>
    User 1:<input name="user" />
    User 2:<input name="user" />
    User 3:<input name="user" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Servlet:**

```
String[] user = request.getParameterValues("user");
```

But if I use jQuery to make an ajax call, and send a array as a parameter, it adds "[]" in the property name

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data:{
        user: ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    }
});
```

Inspecting the header of the request, the data were sent:

**Form Data**

```
user[]=value1&user[]=value2&user[]=value3
```

I know I can add [] at the end of parameter of getParameterValues, but I prefer that jQuery does not send the []

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`traditional` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `true` if you wish to use the traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data:{
        user: ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    },
    traditional: true
});
```

Using this your request will look like:

```
user=value1&user=value2&user=value3
```